# Blank CD/DVD formatting on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

In Windows 10, on insertion of Blank CD, a pop up asks whether the disc would be formatted for use as a USB drive or for use in CD/DVD player. How to achieve the same in ubuntu?

Comment: Can you please clarify your goal?  Do you wish to be able to write to the DVD, file-by-file, and even edit files over a long time period vs the standard 'select a bunch of files, burn to DVD and be done'?  Many of us don't use Windows, so it's not a good point of reference.  Please help describe the functionality you want without dependency on having run Windows 10.

Comment: Just want to write files and delete them on cd-r like its done on pen drives. Windows 10 offers this functionality upon inserting of blank cd-r. Wonder if the same can de done using standard ubuntu distributions!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look at 
⚙️ `Settings | Devices | Removable Media | Other Media... | Blank x Disc`. Assign the application you normally use for optic disk burning there.